# Добавление Redirect при возврате коллекций

Tags: php, laravel

Приветствую программисты, помогите , пожалуйста, добавить Redirect, при возврате коллекций в контроллере. Допустим, вернуться нужно на страницу 'test.php'

```
public function sendIdAndGetHistory(Request $request)
   {

       $this->validate($request, [
           'id' => 'required|max:3',
       ], [
           'id.max' => 'Длина номера карты максимум 3 символа',
           'id.required' => 'Необходимо указать номер карты',
       ]);

       $passNumberCollection = PassNumber::query()->where('pass_id', '=', \request()->get('id'))->get();
       $employeesCollection = Employee::query()->whereIn('id', $passNumberCollection->pluck('id'))->get();

       return [

           'passNumbers' => $passNumberCollection,
           'employees' => $employeesCollection
       ];

   }
```

Comment: Сам я пишу на `Yii2`, но думаю принцип у фреймворков схожий. Если нужно просто перенаправление то `return redirect('home/dashboard');`, если нужно в текущей `view` получить данные и потом перенаправить, то передайте доп. параметр, скажем `redirectURL` вместе с теми, что Вы уже передаете и внутри `view` при его получении сделайте тот же `redirect` средствами `js` т.е `window.location='<?= $redirectURL; ?>'`

Comment: @phpBear , вы не помогли, я пробую сделать:     `  return redirect()->route('show_history_form', ['passNumbers' => $passNumberCollection,
            'employees' => $employeesCollection]); ` , страница перенаправляется, а результат не передается

Comment: Немного непонятен смысл вашего редиректа, верните нужный вам view с параметрами полученными в запросе...вместо редиректа..Опишите в целом задачу, что вы пытаетесь сделать, возможно есть способ реализации лучше..НУ а если вы пытаетесь в роут пихнуть коллекцию, это уже выглядит не правильно

Comment: @Алеша почитайте мануалы по `Laravel` или хотя бы гляньте в код функции `redirect` чтобы понимать, что Вы пытаетесь сделать и почему это не работает. Для Ваших целей подойдет второй вариант предложенный мной.

Comment: @phpBear , второй вариант, предложенный вами мне помог, спасибо.